# Single drive performance in RAID1

Tags: performance, software-raid

I see many tools to measure the performance of RAID1.

But how to measure the performance for **each** SSD in RAID1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You probably can't.

Long answer:

If this is an actual volume behind a hardware RAID controller, you can't unless the RAID controller explicitly supports it. I've never seen a RAID controller that has benchmarking tools, but I guess it's not *impossible*. You can't use third party tools because the drives are abstracted away behind the controller.

For non-hardware RAID (mdadm, storage spaces, zfs, etc) you can sometimes poke the underlying drive using its direct device identifier and not its mount point (go looking for `/dev/sd*` or the Windows equivalent), but every drive benchmarking test I've seen requires a usable file system to read/write from which is usually incompatible with an active RAID partition.